# when an abstract class extends a concrete class, do the inherited members become abstract?

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm getting ready to take my Java 7 Programmer exam and have a question:

when an abstract class extends a concrete class, do the inherited members from the concrete class then become abstract in the abstract class?

I can't find a clear answer so far in the book I am studying; furthermore, Google is spinning me in circles without telling me what I need to know.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd assume if you're studying for a Java 7 exam, you'd have a compiler in front of you.  Why not try it out and see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No they don't become `abstract`. If that was the case, then the below code wouldn't compile:

```
class Test {
    public void hello() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}

abstract class AbstractTest extends Test {  }

class ConcreteTest extends AbstractTest {
    // Inherits the hello() method from AbstractTest, 
    // which in turn inherits it from Test.
}
```

But it compiles fine. Had the `hello()` method become `abstract`, the `ConcreteTest` would have to provide an implementation for that.

However, you can re-declare that method in the `AbstractTest` method as `abstract` and then the `ConcreteTest` class would have to give the implementation for that. So, in this code:

```
class Test {
    public void hello() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
abstract class AbstractTest extends Test {
    public abstract void hello();
}
class ConcreteTest extends AbstractTest {   
}
```

`ConcreteTest` will not compile.

Comment: Thanks for all the detail - it really helped.

Answer (score 2):

No inherited members from concrete class don't become abstract, only if you override them and declare abstract (method members).